# Symbol \u0000 is rendered many times in logs, generated by NLog

Tags: .net, nlog

I'm generating logs with NLog's `JsonLayout` and there are cases where I see such picture on Linux machine:
[image: too many \u0000]
Why can such things are generated? Seems like there is some problem with JSON generation. What is the way to fix this?
My layout:

```
    <variable name="jsonDefaultLayout">
        <layout type="JsonLayout">
            <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
            <attribute name="level" layout="${level}" />
            <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
            <attribute name="activityId" layout="${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}" />
            <attribute name="ip" layout="${aspnet-request-ip}" />
            <attribute name="message" layout="${message:withException=true}" />
            <attribute name="eventProperties" encode="false">
                <layout type='JsonLayout' includeEventProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="10" />
            </attribute>
            <attribute name="hostname" layout="${hostname}" />
            <attribute name="appdomain" layout="${appdomain:format={1\}}" />
        </layout>
    </variable>
```

`\u0000` appear in `message`.

**UPDATE**:
The problem was with this code:

```
 private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            request.EnableBuffering();

            //We now need to read the request stream.  First, we create a new byte[] with the same length as the request stream...
            var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
  
            var stream = request.BodyReader.AsStream(true);
            await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            string log = $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";
            return new
            {
                Url = log,
                Body = LogInputSanitizer(bodyAsText)
            }.ToJson(Formatting.None);
        }
```

When I've changed the way I read the stream to:

```
  request.EnableBuffering();
  string bodyAsText = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

Everything seems fixed now. **Guys, thanks for the comments!**
The question that is left for me:
**What was the problem with the old code?**

Comment: Likely logging content full of null characters/bytes would reasonably do this. Do you have a short re-create that can be included in this answer?

Comment: @Richard this seems completely random in my case, that's why I can't provide the sample that generates it, but I'll add the layout...

Comment: NLog writes what you give it to write. Post your real code. What that image shows is the proper way to encode `NUL` characters in JSON. The top of the image seems to contain non-NUL contents too, which means one of the application's logging calls actually wrote a buffer full of NULs to the log

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok, thanks, I'll check the place this log was generated from and post it here..

Comment: Look for code that tries to log JSON strings. What you posted looks like JSON that was serialized inside another JSON string, which means all special characters like ``"` had to be escaped. Something serializes objects that have `LengthOfStay` and similar properties to JSON, then logs that JSON

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is just a request body... Ops.. probably this one is the cause of the problem:
```
        private string LogInputSanitizer(string input)
        {
            // Replace for example "password":"blabla" with "password": null
            return _skipNameList.Aggregate(input,
                (current, name) =>
                    Regex.Replace(current, $"\"{name}\":\"\\S+\"", $"\"{name}\": null"));
        }
```

Comment: [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) already supports request logging and storing the request in a usable form. You gain little by including an entire request in your application logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered then NLog is just outputting the provided property-value, and in this case a string-value containing only null-chars.

The string-value comes from your `FormatRequest`-method that converts byte-array to string, but if byte-array is not filled with any data then it becomes string-value with only null-chars.

When using Read / ReadAsync from a stream, then one must check the return value to see how many bytes has been read. This should done in a loop until receiving zero bytes meaning end-of-stream. When using StreamReader then it handles everything for you (including recognizing encoding).

Consider changing your code to this:

```cs
private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
{
   var contentLength = request.ContentLength;
   if (contentLength <= 0)
        return string.Empty; // What if 100 MByte ?

   request.EnableBuffering();
   string bodyAsText = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
   return bodyAsText;
}
```

Notice NLog.Web.AspNetCore provides [${aspnet-request-posted-body}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-posted-body-layout-renderer) (Instead of inserting into LogEventInfo-properties). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/HTTP-Request-Logging

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the answer. In the new implementation I've already added the code that rechecks for length of the request: if its  > 6mb - leave 4mb, trim other part and just add the last 300 chars... Not that optimal, but if request contains that much information - it will be saved somewhere else, not needed in logs in my case.

Comment: As about HTTP-Request-Logging - we will consider that in the future: now we have specific formatting and attributes for log ignore for some methods. In case of HTTP-Request-Logging as I see it will log all the requests. Anyway that needs some practical experiments, thank you for mentioning.